# Salvetti complexes and cohomology of affine completion of Artin groups $E_6$ and $E_7$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology, hyperplane-arrangements

After  the  solution of  the Brieskorn-Arnold Pham conjecture on  the  asphericity of  a space for affine Artin groups by  Paolini and Salvetti MR4243019 ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11795)), I would like to know if there are cohomology computations for the  affine completion of the sporadic Artin  groups $E_6$  and $E_7$ based  on  the  Salvetti complex, or if bounds on the virtual cohomological dimension are known.